# Get handle of NumericUpDown's edit part

Tags: c#, .net, numericupdown

A `NumericUpDown` has 2 handles/controls: the outer spinbox, and the inner edit textbox-like control.

I need to get the handle of the inner textbox control. `NumericUpDown.Handle` gives the outer handle.

The closest I found on Google to that is this [this forum conversation](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/select-text-numericupdown-control-t1307779.html). The trick is to use the `UDM_GETBUDDY = WM_USER+106 = 0x0400+106` message which returns the handle of the buddy window, in our case the text edit.

The output was something like this at first:

```
control.Capture = true;
IntPtr outer = User32.GetCapture();
IntPtr inner = new IntPtr(User32.SendMessage(outer, (0x0400 + 106), 0, 0));
```

But then the OP said this wasn't working, so someone suggested to use `GetWindow(outer, GW_CHILD)`. where `GW_CHILD = 5`

```
control.Capture = true;
IntPtr outer = User32.GetCapture();
IntPtr inner = User32.GetWindow(outer, 5);
```

For both of these methods, I always end up with `inner = 0`, which is obviously not the right answer. However, OP stated method 2 seemed to work, so I might be doing something wrong.

By the way, the "capture" mechanic seems to be useless, as I can simply use:

```
IntPtr outer = control.Handle;
```

Which returns the same.

So, any ideas on how to get the inner textbox handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented very differently in Winforms, no buddy control.  Getting a reference to the text box portion is easy to do, although it violates several encapsulation rules.  Not really a problem, NumericUpDown is frozen in time and will never change.

```
        var box = (TextBox)numericUpDown1.Controls[1];
```

Be careful with poking properties for that TextBox control, not all of its events are implemented.

Comment: Wow, yummy. Without any P/Invoke, too! I'll disregard the fact that I'm breaking rules (P/Invoke would've been worse a felony, now wouldn't it?). Thanks!